# How to loop over selected columns in python pandas.

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that has variables named like this :

```
   exp1 exp2 exp3 
    10   20   56
```

I have a function that takes exp1 as an argument and create a variable named rate1. Now I would like to modify the function to loop over exp1 , 2 , 3 etc and create rate1 ,2 ,3 etc. I am new to python. What is the proper way to do this simple task.

Comment: Normally, to get the best out of pandas, you should avoid loops and try to 'vectorize' your operations/functions if you can. It's hard to give a good answer to this question as it depends very much on the function. If you give the function it will help. Also, your sample dataframe is not very descriptive as it only has one row and could be described by a pandas series instead. I didn't vote you down though :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just change `FUNCTION` by your function

```py
rates = []
for column in df:
   # if your function deal with columns as dataframe
   rate = FUNCTION(df[column])
   rates.append(rate)

   # if your function deal with columns as lists
   rate = FUNCTION(df[column].values)
   rates.append(rate)

   # if your dataframes contain one value (row) and your function deal with this values as floats
   rate = FUNCTION(float(df[column].values))
   rates.append(rate)
print rates
```